# nginx rewrite rules wildcards

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am trying to do the following nginx redirect

`/product/reports/v1/stores(/|$)(.*)`

to

`/stores(/|$)(.*)`

seems like it should be simple but I can not get it to work. My intention is to use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the destination you likely need to use `/stores$1$2` to use the capture groups specified in the source definition.